# Silverlight and reading local directory

Tags: c#, silverlight

Im trying to clone facebook image uploader which is built in java. But I would like to use silverlight so Im wondering if I can somehow read local directory.

If I have this running an some remote server I can easily read the content of that server as I have C# as backend. But Im not sure how could I read certain directory of the user which is using silverlight application.

Any ideas if this is possible or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to read file "blindly" using *OpenFileDialog*. Blindly means you can let the user point the dialog to the file so Silverlight can read its content but it can't tell where the file is located.

Example:

```
var fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
var dialog = fileDialog.ShowDialog();
if (dialog.HasValue && dialog.Value)
{
    byte[] bytes;
    using (var fileReader = fileDialog.File.OpenRead())
    {
        bytes = new byte[fileReader.Length];
        fileReader.Read(bytes, 0, (int) fileReader.Length);
    }
}
```

The access to the file system is limited for security. Some access (blind as well) can be done using [Isolated Storage](http://silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/isolatedstorage/) where you can store data and access later.